# How can I pass calculated amount to state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I pass `currentBook, currentUnits and calculated total` during on click on the Record button
Now it just displays the entered value under the purchased book section. I would like to display the data and calculated amount during on click on Record button. Could someone please advise

ie Amount = units * price

for example it should display following result **1. Mathematics  6  300**

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-grass-gwpf9?file=/src/App.js

[image]

```
function App() {

  const [currentBook, setCurrentBook] = useState('')
  const [currentUnits, setCurrentUnits] = useState('')
  const [currentPrice, setCurrentPrice] = useState('')
  const [currentRecord, setCurrentRecord] = useState({book:'', units:'', price:''});

    
  const changeBook = (newBook) => {
    setCurrentBook(newBook);
  }

  const changeUnits = (newunits) => {
    setCurrentUnits(newunits);
  }

  const changePrice = (newprice) => {
    setCurrentPrice(newprice);
  }

  const calculateTotal = (e) => {
    var cal_total = currentUnits * currentPrice;
    setCurrentRecord(currentBook, currentUnits, cal_total );
    //setCurrentRecord({ ...currentRecord, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Online Shopping</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flexbox-container">
        <div className="maintransaction">
          <h3>Choose a book</h3>
          <div className="container">
            <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={(event) => changeBook(event.target.value)}>
              <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose a book ...</option>
              <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
              <option value="science">Science</option>
              <option value="english">English</option>
              <option value="German">German</option>
            </select>
          </div><br></br>
          <div className="quantity">
            <span className="units">
              <label>Units</label>
              <input name="units" type="text" onChange={(event) => changeUnits(event.target.value)}></input>
            </span>
            <span className="price">
              <label>Price</label>
              <input name="price" type="text" onChange={(event) => changePrice(event.target.value)}></input>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="recordBtn">
            <button onClick={(event) => calculateTotal()}>Record</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="purchasedbooks">
          <h3>Purchased book:</h3>
            <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Item no</th>
                    <th>Books</th>
                    <th>Units</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                  </tr>
                  {
                    //currentRecord.map(({ currentBook, currentUnits }) => (
                    <tr>
                    <td>1.</td>
                    <td>{currentBook}</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>250</td>
                  </tr>
                   // ))
                  }
                  
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have made some modification. Do I just need to save and you can see the changes?

Comment: Can you please save so that I would be able to see

Comment: check the link I provide down below the answer

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 Appreciate your help, one question... is it destructuring of object happening at this line ``const newRecord = [...currentRecord, recentNewRecord];`` ?

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted ans

Comment: Yes, deconstruct what is already in the ```currentRecord```, combining with the ```newRecord```. Glad that I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several changes have been made in the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hellman-r5cgh?file=/src/App.js)

1. Calculate the total when click `record` as asked in the question
2. Add some checking when user press the record button. Three inputs need to be filled in.
3. The input type should be `number` but not `text` since it may need to NaN if user enter string in the input.
4. Implementing a button to reset all the record.
5. Use `map` for rendering `currentRecord`

Comment: The sandbox looks that it does what you need

Comment: @poPaTheGuru What do you mean?

Comment: From your original post, I see that your problem was that the amount wasn't calculated right.  Now i tried your sandbox code and it shows the right amount if I insert 2 for quantity and 5 for price for eg.

Comment: @poPaTheGuru I am not the one who ask this question. I just passed by and wanna ask the question. :))

Comment: ooops, sorry, though that the OP just put an answer with the updated link, sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `map` should look like this:

```
    {currentRecord.map(item => (
        <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>{item.currentBook}</td>
        <td>{item.units}</td>
        <td>{item.price}</td>
        </tr>
      ))
     }
```

Comment: Sorry it is giving an error, 
TypeError: currentRecord.map is not a function

Comment: Write the `currentRecord` like this: 
`const [currentRecord, setCurrentRecord] = useState([{book:'', units:'', price:''}]);`